# Automated data collection from a website into my database?

Tags: python, django, webfaction

I've got a Django-based website using a PostgreSQL database hosted on Webfaction.  I normally manually collect the data for my database (copy-paste into a text file) from another website which lists all of the data on a single web page in an HTML table.

As far as automatically gathering that data with Python, I'm guessing that I should use something like html5lib or Scrapy to write a script that loads the web page, finds the HTML table I want, extracts the data from it, formats it into JSON, and then uses

```
manage.py loaddata fixturename.json
```

to load my data into my database.  My question, though, is how do I get this script to run automatically once a day on Webfaction's server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to schedule tasks.

Your crontab file could look something like this:

```
# Minute   Hour   Day of Month       Month          Day of Week        Command    
# (0-59)  (0-23)     (1-31)    (1-12 or Jan-Dec)  (0-6 or Sun-Sat)                
    0        1          *             *               *           /usr/bin/python manage.py loaddata fixturename.json
```

(Or you can use `@daily /usr/bin/python manage.py loaddata fixturename.json` to run at midnight every night)

See the webfaction documentation: http://docs.webfaction.com/software/general.html#scheduling-tasks-with-cron

Answer (score 1):

You could YQL to scrap websites for you and return the results in json format.I extensively use YQL to get data for my apps.Its fast and your server doesn't have to take the load for it .

http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/

To run the script once a day you can try adding it to a cron job

http://docs.webfaction.com/software/general.html#scheduling-tasks-with-cron

http://garrett.im/django/sysadmin/2011/10/03/cron-django-webfaction.html

Answer (score 1):

You want to run a CRON job.  It's a simle way to get a server to run a job once or repeatedly on any schedule you set.

Also make sure you have permission to screen scrape someone else's content.

Answer (score 1):

Cron or celerybeat are good options. Cron is easier, celery gives you more control

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html